# Dataframe manipulation in python Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

What is the most efficient way to convert a pandas dataframe with each individual rows like this:

```
    p1  p2  prog
0   A   B   C
```

into 3 lines like this?

```
    n1  n2  edge_type
0   A   A/B marriage
1   B   A/B marriage
2   A/B C   child
```

or equivalently, converting `df` to `DF` as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'prog':['C'], 'p1': ['A'], 'p2': ['B']})
dF = pd.DataFrame({'edge_type':['marriage', 'marriage', 'child'], 'n1': ['A', 'B', 'A/B'], 'n2': ['A/B', 'A/B', 'C']})
```

It is straightforward with defining a worker function and use `mapply` in `R`, but I am still scratching my head on doing that in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `apply`:

```
def func(s):
    combo = '/'.join([s['p1'], s['p2']])
    l = [[s['p1'], combo, 'marriage'], [s['p2'], combo, 'marriage'], [combo, s['prog'], 'child']]
    return pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['n1', 'n2', 'edge_type']).unstack()
```

Then with your example:

```
df.apply(func, axis=1).stack().reset_index(drop=True)
```

returns

```
    n1   n2 edge_type
0    A  A/B  marriage
1    B  A/B  marriage
2  A/B    C     child
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why it gives `---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-0752ed438839> in <module>()
----> 1 combo = '/'.join([G_df['p1'], G_df['p2']])

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, Series found` when I'm trying to build `combo` outside the function?

Comment: Although the function works just fine for this example, I get the same type of error above when I'm trying to apply this function on other dataframes. FYI. `TypeError: ('sequence item 0: expected str instance, numpy.float64 found', 'occurred at index 0')`

Comment: @Rotail It's hard to debug in the comments... Try asking another question with a [**Minimal, Complete, Verifiable** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and I'll take a look!

Comment: sure, will do. But before that, I just noticed your solution need a little bit of modification for this question. It returns `A` and `B` in the first and second rows. However, it is supposed to return, `A` and `A/B` in the first row and `B` and `A/B` in the second row. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'prog':['C'], 'p1': ['A'], 'p2': ['B']})

data = []
for row in df.itertuples():
    for i in range(1,4):
        if i in (1,2):
            data.append(('marriage', row[i], '/'.join([row[1], row[2]])))
        else:
            data.append(('child', '/'.join([row[1], row[2]]), row[i]))
dF = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=('edge_type', 'n1', 'n2'))
```

I tried apply function but ended up with a very hackish solution. I am sure there are better solutions.

Comment: I tried this over the example above. This does not return the proper mix.

Comment: @Rotail What error/ output are you getting? Works just fine for me.

Comment: No error. It just doesn't return what is supposed to return in above example.